# Best approach to auditing in Laravel & Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, audit

I have a web API which interacts with mobile apps. Mobile users can currently create create and edit objects. I want to add in functionality where administrators in the web application can also make edits, but I need to work out a way to also introduce an audit trail, possibly with approvals for edits.

For any of you who have built such functionality in the past, were there any resources you used to make the process easier? Was there anything you could plug and play? What is your advice on approaching this, when you have two sources (web application and mobile app) in which edits can be made to items (at the end of the day, the web app users call the shots).

Here are some resources I have looked at so far. There do appear to be a few solutions, but I would be interested to hear your experiences. Much appreciated!

- http://www.kode-blog.com/2014/03/eloquent-orm-slim-framework-tutorial-real-world-example/
- https://github.com/olsgreen/laravel-auditable
- https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable#display
- https://github.com/rmasters/culpa
- https://gist.github.com/tortuetorche/6778223
- https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1238-audit-logging/0

So far, the VentureCraft Revisionable seems to be the solution with the most development.

Comment: For revisions check out this package as well https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable . It's in early stages of dev, but it offers different approach to what `VentureCraft` one does (which is I suppose the only one worth mentioning here). Currently it tracks changes to the models, but in future it will also let you approve the changes (probably as an another, compatible package).

Comment: Awesome @JarekTkaczyk . Thanks for the reference. I suppose that this should see further development given that "This package requires PHP 5.4+ and Currently it works out of the box with Laravel5 + generic Illuminate Guard OR catalyst/sentry 2"

Comment: Yes, it's pretty fresh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726400/laravel-auditing-eloquent-events-or-alternatives